# JNA Pointer cast to struct

Tags: pointers, casting, jna

I have a pointer in a struct. And I passed a struct pointer to this pointer.

But I could not type cast back to this pointer to struct.

```
public class Test
{

     //
     Pointer ptr = new Memory(4);
}

public class Temp extends Structure
{

     //

}

Test tst = new Test();
Temp tmp = new Temp();

tst.ptr = tmp.getPointer();

...

Temp newTmp = (Temp)tst.ptr.getPointer(); // This is not working.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new structure cast onto the memory using the [`Structure(Pointer p)`](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.1/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Structure.html#Structure%28com.sun.jna.Pointer%29) constructor:

```
Temp newTmp = new Temp(tst.ptr.getPointer());
```